# friend function of the class can't access to its private vector;

Tags: c++, private, friend

I have the following declaration:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&,const List&);
```

and I have the following definition:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out,const List& item) {
    vector<List::Employee>::const_iterator It;
    for (It=item.employees.begin();It!=item.employees.end();It++) {}
}
```

---

Employee is a structure of mine own,and employees is a private vector of Employee in class List. The compiler gives me the following errors:

```
std::vector<List::Employee,std::allocator<List::Employee>> List::employees is private
```

any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: where is the friend declaration? remember friendship is not inherited...

Comment: it's in the public method of the class

Comment: A *method* ?? Do you mean the class decl (the List class, btw)?

Comment: Yes,I decl the output operator as a friend function of the class(in the public)

Comment: Which class is the friend declaration in - is it in the `List` class or the `Employee` class?

Comment: Employee is a structure.It's declared in the List class

Comment: Why C tag is used here? I can't find anything related to C in the question

Comment: @user1831226 fwiw, the public location of the friend'ing has nothing to do with it. Friending is a boolean condition; either you are, or you aren't. the only thing left then is the decl in the class does not match the decl of the free-operator function. check them again.

Comment: Can you reproduce the error in a small, self-contained program?

Comment: So is the friend declaration in the `List class` or in the `Employee structure`?

Comment: it's friend declaration of the List class.

Answer (score 0):

The friend declaration should be inside the List class definition.

```
class List{
    ...
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&,const List&);
};
```

Comment: Pretty sure that was what the OP meant when he said "...It's declared in the List class".